# LTI integration with Laravel websites as LMS

Tags: php, laravel, lti, phplib

There're two websites of educational courses. I own the one built with Laravel.
I want to access another website's courses into my website.

***So basically I want to integrate LTI for my website.***

I have checked this latest package of [IMSGlobal LTI version 1.3](https://github.com/IMSGlobal/lti-1-3-php-library)

I made tool and platform here https://lti-ri.imsglobal.org/,

Created this AppDatabase.php class in my laravel website to set auth login url,client id, etc

```
namespace App\LTI;

use IMSGlobal\LTI\Database;
use IMSGlobal\LTI\LTI_Registration;

class AppDatabase implements Database {
    public function find_registration_by_issuer($iss) {

        return LTI_Registration::new()
                ->set_auth_login_url('https://lti-ri.imsglobal.org/platforms/2820/authorizations/new')
                ->set_auth_token_url('https://lti-ri.imsglobal.org/platforms/2820/access_tokens')
                ->set_client_id('12345')
                ->set_key_set_url('https://lti-ri.imsglobal.org/platforms/2820/platform_keys/2601.json')
                ->set_kid('jLLLqXRObQ2JX2Q9RC0h6F8hn0OrSnAK_lc5UMYztHQ')
                ->set_issuer('example.com')
                ->set_tool_private_key(file_get_contents(__DIR__ .'/'. 'private.key'));
    }

    public function find_deployment($iss, $deployment_id) {
        return LTI\LTI_Deployment::new()
            ->set_deployment_id($deployment_id);
    }
}
```

I tried following instructions from https://github.com/IMSGlobal/lti-1-3-php-library , but could not get any output. I'm trying these on my localhost.

I need someone to guide me, because I'm completely lost here.